# how to solve this error when upgrade from core 2.1 to core 3.1 OptionsValidationException: Cookie.Expiration is ignored, use ExpireTimeSpan instead

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-2.1

I have upgraded my asp.net core 2.1 application to asp.net core 3.1, but when I run the project I got this error `OptionsValidationException: Cookie. Expiration is ignored, use ExpireTimeSpan instead.` the first display of my application show this error

here is my startup code asp.net core 3.1, that I have upgraded from .net core 2.1,

```
  public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Environment = environment;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DentalDBconnection");
        services.AddDbContext<HoshmandDBContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddAuthentication(option =>
        {
            option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            option.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            option.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Logins/UserLogin/";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
            options.Cookie.Expiration = new TimeSpan(10, 00, 00);
        });

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;

        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(option =>
        {
            option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(540);
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("HasAccess", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new HasAccessRequirment()));
        });
        // services.AddTransient<IFingerPrint, FingerPrint>();
        services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, HasAccessHandler>();
        services.AddTransient<IMvcControllerDiscovery, MvcControllerDiscovery>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        var cachePeriod = Environment.IsDevelopment() ? "600" : "604800";
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
            {
                ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", $"public, max-age={cachePeriod}");
            }
        });
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=UserProfiles}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

please help me, what else I need to change when upgrating from asp.net core 2.1 to asp.net core 3.1 to not got this error Thank you

**New Section Code Added**

I think the issue is somewhere else by default in my startup code user redirects to this controller, from EndPoint

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=UserProfiles}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

in UserProfile Controller there is, a check if a user is not login, this function redirects to the user's login page

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(bool? passIsChanged = null) // userId
    {
        if (passIsChanged != null)
        {
            ViewBag.isSuccessed = passIsChanged;
        }
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
        var user = _context.UserAccountTbs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserId == id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("UserLogin", "Logins");
        }
```

From UserProfile when GO to the login page this Error Happens

Answer (score 0):

Use `options.ExpireTimeSpan` instead of `options.Cookie.Expiration` (which, yes, is ignored).

```
services.AddAuthentication(...)
   .AddCookie(options =>
   {
       options.LoginPath = "/Logins/UserLogin/";
       options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
       options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(10, 00, 00);
   });
```

Comment: Dear Chen, I have replaced that line of code but got a new error as below, that says your login view page is not found,/Views/Logins/UserLogin.cshtml.
 here in this directory, I have my Login view page available, before adding this code options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(10, 00, 00);  my login view page is working fine when  I add this code this error occurs 

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The view 'UserLogin' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Logins/UserLogin.cshtml
/Views/Shared/UserLogin.cshtml

Comment: I have changed my code to this but again the error says that login view page is not found 

            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Views/Logins/UserLogin.cshtml";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(10);
            });

Comment: Can you share your directory structure? @Hedayat Hoshmand

Comment: Yes, It's MVC

Users\\Desktop\Myproject\Views\Logins\UserLogin.cshtml

This login page is working before I change my startup code to asp.net core 3.1 when I add this line of code options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(10, 00, 00); this error found, @Chen

Comment: I have posted another question with the same issue , that view not found 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74623093/invalidoperationexception-the-view-userlogin-was-not-found-when-migrate-from

@Chen

Comment: It doesn't look like a problem, try to exclude the view and include again in to project. @Hedayat Hoshmand

Comment: Note that the redirection path should be “/controller/action”.

Comment: I think the issue is somewhere else, I have added to my Question @Chen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250007/discussion-between-hedayat-hoshmand-and-chen).

Comment: Is the successfully redirected URL in the controller the same as the failed redirected URL in Startup? @Hedayat Hoshmand

Comment: Yes the are same