# InvalidOperationException: The view 'UserLogin' was not found, when migrate from asp.net core 2.1 to asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

I have migrated my asp.net core 2.1 to asp.net core 3.1, but I got this error in my startup code,
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The view 'UserLogin' was not found. The following locations were searched:

```
 /Views/Logins/UserLogin.cshtml
```

My Login page View is exist and is available in this directory

```
 /Views/Logins/UserLogin.cshtml
```

before migration, this works fine, but when I changed my Startup code to asp.net core 3.1 this error happens

Here is my Startup Code:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DentalDBconnection");
        services.AddDbContext<HoshmandDBContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddAuthentication(option =>
        {
            option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            option.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            option.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Views/Logins/UserLogin.cshtml";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(10);
        });

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;

        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(option =>
        {
            option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(540);
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("HasAccess", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new HasAccessRequirment()));
        });
        // services.AddTransient<IFingerPrint, FingerPrint>();
        services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, HasAccessHandler>();
        services.AddTransient<IMvcControllerDiscovery, MvcControllerDiscovery>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=UserProfiles}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Please help how to solve this error

Here is my Controller Login code

```
  public class LoginsController : BaseController
{
    public LoginsController(HoshmandDBContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => View(new Login()));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin([FromForm] Login currentUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = currentUser.RememberMe,
                AllowRefresh = false,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(10)
            };

            UserAccountTb user = _context.UserAccountTbs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserName.Equals(currentUser.UserName));
            if (user == null)
            {
                TempData["UserLoginFailed"] = "Login Failed: Please Enter Correct Credential";
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                // validate the password
                if (user.Password.Equals(currentUser.Password))
                {
                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                            {
                                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserId.ToString()),
                            };
                    List<int?> userGroupIds = new List<int?>();

                    if (user.Level)
                    {
                        user.Emp = _context.EmployeeTbs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.EmpId == user.EmpId);
                        if (user.Emp != null)
                        {
                            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.Emp.FirstName + " " + user.Emp.LastName));
                            userGroupIds = (from u in _context.UserAccountTbs.Where(a => a.EmpId == user.EmpId)
                                            select u.GroupId).ToList();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "Administrator"));
                        userGroupIds.Add(1);
                    }

                    // adding all role to user via loop in claims
                    foreach (var groupId in userGroupIds)
                    {
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, groupId.ToString()));
                    }
                    ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login"));
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal, properties);
                    //return RedirectToAction("Default", "Home", new { id = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name) });

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "UserProfiles", new { id = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name) });
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["UserLoginFailed"] = "Login Failed: Please Enter Correct Credential";
                    return View();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```

I think the issue is somewhere else by default in my startup code user redirects to this controller, from EndPoint

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=UserProfiles}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

in UserProfile Controller there is, a check if a user is not login, this function redirects to the user's login page

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(bool? passIsChanged = null) // userId
    {
        if (passIsChanged != null)
        {
            ViewBag.isSuccessed = passIsChanged;
        }
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
        var user = _context.UserAccountTbs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserId == id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("UserLogin", "Logins");
        }
```

From UserProfile when GO to the login page this Error Happens

Comment: Did you create a controller for it?

Comment: I have added my login controller code in the above question section 

@ViniciusAndrade

Comment: `options.LoginPath = "/Views/Logins/UserLogin.cshtml";` should be `options.LoginPath = "/Views/Logins/UserLogin";`.The path doesn't need to contain `.cshtml`.

Comment: I have removed that, but it does not work

I think the issue is somewhere else 

by default in my startup code user redirect to this controller, from EndPoint  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=UserProfiles}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

in UserProfile there, check if a user is not login , this function redirects to user's login page 

 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(bool? passIsChanged = null) // userId
            if (user == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("UserLogin", "Logins");
            }

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have already created, but in order to return a view you **need** to create a **controller** for it

This controller must have a simple [HttpGet] method that will return it's correspondent view.

Ex:

```cs
//...imports
namespace Application.Api.Admin.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class UserLoginController :Controller
    {

        public UserLoginController(ILogger<UserLoginController> logger) 
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        //... Other methods
    }
}
```

But I think the main problem of your code is that you are setting the wrong path in **options.LoginPath**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  //...code 
 .AddCookie(options =>
        {
           //The name of the  controller
            options.LoginPath = "/UserLogin";
          //... code
        });
  //..code
}
```

Comment: Yes, @ViniciusAndrade I have created a controller, this project is now working in production with the same code, when I update it to asp.net core 3.1 and change my Startup Code this error happens, 

Here is my controller code

Comment: I have added my login controller code in the above question section 

@ViniciusAndrade

Comment: Why you can't return just View()?

Comment: Where In my Startup Code or Login Code? @ViniciusAndrade

Comment: I posted this question before this error happen in another post, after solving that issue this new issue happens, Can you please see this link once @ViniciusAndrade

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74611798/how-to-solve-this-error-when-upgrade-from-core-2-1-to-core-3-1-optionsvalidation

Comment: Could you try changing `endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=UserProfiles}/{action=Index}/{id?}");` to `endpoints.MapControllers();`